# What is wrong with this jquery expression?

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to select all my textboxes with...

```
$("input[@type=text]")
```

From the jquery docs it seems this should be valid syntax.

Down the page at http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors there is an example given...

```
$("input[@type=radio][@checked]")
```

... which is very similar to what my expression does.  When I 'watch' my expression with FireBug I get a

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@type='text']
```

error.

I have tried ...

`$("input[@type='text']")` as well to no avail.  I appreciate any tips!

Comment: Are you using version 1.1.2 of jQuery? I believe the `@` syntax was deprecated and you ought to be looking at the [current documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) if you are using a more recent version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API documentation you're looking at is old (probably based on XPath selectors). You want to look at the [attribute-equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector. There's also other attribute selectors (contains, starts with, etc) if you're interested.

`$("input[type='text']")` should work for you

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/hCRkW/

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  The docs state to use an ampersand.  When I took that out it works as expected now.  THANKS!!

Comment: @John, for clarity shake, **at sign** (@) is not **ambersand** (&).

Comment: Your linked docs also state "This is an old version of the Selectors API: View the Current API".

Comment: @Gaby, ahh, yes, misstated my symbol.  Meant 'at sign'.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('input:text')
```

And:

```
$('input:radio')
```

The @ selectors were deprecated in jQuery 1.2, and I believe disappeared in 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `$('input[type="text"]')`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('input[type=text]')`.

I think in older version of jquery you needed the @ sign before the attribute name. Newer version don't want it.

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/